# Javascript function callback for php code

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to send data from function to ajax call using callback function.

I have function:

```
function CallAfterLogin(data,callback){
        FB.login(function(response) {  //---
        if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate(); 
            FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) {
            console.log(mydata);
              if(mydata.email == null)
              {
                 alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                 ResetAnimate();
              }else {
                alert("hi");
                callback(data); // <=== Trigger the callback
            }
              }); //--
         } //if
             }); //---
```

Which I am calling on button click event:

`<button type="button" onclick="CallAfterLogin()" ?>Click Me!</button>`

I want to send data to `ajaxResponse()` function:

```
function AjaxResponse()
 {
    document.CallAfterLogin(mydata, function(send) {
        var myData = 'connect=1'; 
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_facebook.php",
        data: {
                   connect: 1,
                   myd: mydata      //
                  }
                  }).done(function(result) {
                        $("#fb-root").html(result);
                     });
               });
  }
```

Above code works till `callback(data); // <=== Trigger the callback` and then in Firebug I could not see any error or warning. It shows `profiler is running` for few seconds and then no activity.

I think there's issue after call to `callback(data);` Can someone give me what is the issue here?
I tried to call `ajaxResponse()` function on buttonclick event but it makes no action.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

I need to use:

`<button type="button" onclick="AjaxResponse()" ?>Click Me!</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Does firebug show the "hi" text being written to the console?  Where is the code for the 'callback(data)' function? Did you mean to call the 'CallAfterLogin' function at that point?

Comment: Yes, "Hi" get prompted. I think I dont need to code callback as per tutotials I show for callback function. I mean to call ajaxResponse somehow and get `data` there.