# Using callback function with doument object

Tags: javascript

Call back function works fine for:

```
function mySandwich(param1, param2, callback) {  
    alert('Started eating my sandwich.\n\nIt has: ' + param1 + ', ' + param2);  
    callback();  
}  

mySandwich('ham', 'cheese', function() {  
    alert('Finished eating my sandwich.');  
});
```

in  inside body tag.

When I tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function CallAfterLogin()
    {
        document.mySandwich('hi',function(send){ 
        alert("finished");
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="CallAfterLogin()">Click Me!</button> 
<script>
    function mySandwich(param1, callback) {  
        alert('Started eating my sandwich.\n\nIt has: ' + param1 );  
        callback();  
    }  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives error: document.mySandwich is not defined.
Can someone tell me where is the issue?

Comment: @DaveChen—you should post answers as answers, not comments, that way others will know the question is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mySandwich` is not a function attached to the document object, it is function in the global scope, so instead of `document.mySandwich(...)` just use `mySandwich(...)`

```
function CallAfterLogin() {
    mySandwich('param1', 'param2', function(send){ 
        alert("finished");
    });
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate your help if you could review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179657/javascript-function-callback-for-php-code my question !